# Declined Flag Feedback

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, flag-ban

My focus in 2018 is gaining more experience in moderating questions and answers. As a result I've been hitting the review queues hard. And as a result of that I earned myself a ban on flagging - 4 declined flags in the past week.

In general I understand the reason my flags were declined. However, I'd like some feedback on one particular declined flag.

Here's the [link to the question/answer in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47375788/install-nunit-with-visual-studio-2017/48069481#48069481).

The answer I flagged is:

> It worked for me, I installed Nuget Packages: NUnit, Nunit3TestAdapter and Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk, after I saved the solution and closed Visual Studio then I opened solution again.

which is very similar to the only other existing answer, which recommends installing the NuGet Packages. To me, this makes the above answer seem like a "thank you" or "me too" answer.

What is the appropriate action for this answer? Skip? No action? Different flag?

Comment: Skip is never wrong.

Comment: Of the two answers on that question, the one you flagged contained more actionable info then the other answer. That is basically a link-only answer with just enough info that make it pass an NAA verdict. At first sight I wouldn't have flagged that answer and when looked at in context, I might consider a flag for the other answer, but I won't be surprised if my flag ends-up declined.

Comment: @rene Without even clicking on the link, I could see that the answer was to install nunit via nuget and not via _Tools->Extensions And Updates_

Comment: @rene That is true. However, I feel a Skip only passes the issue to the next moderator. And no amount of Skips will resolve the review. So shouldn't I strive to arrive at a No Action, Comment, Flag, etc? Basically anything but Skip.

Comment: No, you should strive for your solid judgement on a review. If you have doubts, skip.

Comment: @SamIam points for you then, I only arrived at that conclusion now that you mention it. It might be less obvious for inexperienced VS users. Still not thrilled by that answer.

Comment: Hmm, if you hate to skip because it passes the job to somebody else then do consider what a flag actually does.  It is worse.  Beyond possibly occupying the time of up to five users, it may have to be handled by somebody that is really busy and has better things to do.  Guaranteed he won't.  Just fix it yourself, use your right to vote.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I agree with you that it's in essence a "thank you" answer, but I can understand how, at first glance, it might not be recognized as such.

Generally speaking, Moderators tend not to delete answers for being somewhat similar to another answer.  They also don't delete answers for being outright wrong.  If it kinda looks like it can be used as an answer it will usually stick.

Moderators make mistakes, and misread things occasionally.

If I were you, I'd still flag, but If I doubted the obviousness of the reason for flagging, I'd instead use a custom flag reason which allows you to more specifically state why you're flagging.

Comment: I declined the flag there. I agree largely with all the parts of the answer, except for the starting para that mentions that the answer is  "a thank you answer". It certainly is *not* a thank you answer. They clearly have 1. listed out the packages which have to be installed 2. Steps to be taken after installing. The other answer is a partial link-only which informs that you need to install Nuget packages. I did check the entire post (there were around 6 flags in the SO mod queue, which is toooo less), and then declined it after that. (Apart from that, the rest of the answer is perfect)

Comment: Please do not downvote this answer like I did without looking into [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48069481/revisions). Now I'd like to withdraw my downvote (but I can't, sorry), because *"It worked for me"* is indeed looks like "thank you" answer (not exactly "thank you", more like "it worked for me too" - kind of confirmation, what **another answer** solves the problem).

Comment: *"I did check the entire post"* This is good advice for flaggers and reviewers, too. If some post looks like a thank you answer at first glance, but has some content on its own, check if there is another answer (or at least a comment) this could be a thank you comment to. In this case, that would have directly prevented the incorrect flag. (Yes, it's more work, but better review at low volume correctly than forcing high volume at the expense of accuracy.)

Comment: Ah, look a wild @BhargavRao \o

Comment: @BaummitAugen it more or less reiterates what the other answer said to do.  It doesn't seem to have any novel ideas that weren't in the other answer.  It just has a more granular series of steps.

Comment: @SamIam "More or less reiterating" is not the same as saying thanks. If it was something along the lines of "'(partial) copy pasta' worked for me", things would be different. But this answer stands on its own and provides extra information, as Bhargav Rao already mentioned. *"It just has a more granular series of steps."* That's generally good enough.

Comment: @kayess \o (bit busy these days :(...)

Comment: @Bhargav Rao: An answer isn't guaranteed to be an attempt at answering just because it contains content that would have been seen as an answer. I've deleted more than a few answers that looked like answers but in reality were 1) plagiarized from elsewhere 2) *really* thank-you answers because they have a "thank you" or "it worked for me" slapped on before or after the copied content. In this case, the answer doesn't appear to be plagiarized, but nevertheless the position of "It worked for me" (emphasis on "It") is quite unusual in English writing...

Comment: ... and I can see why someone might have misconstrued it as a thank-you answer anyway. On the other hand, had the answer started with "Here's what worked for me:" (putting aside the ideal of just omitting the noise altogether), it would have less likely been seen as a thank-you answer.

Comment: @BoltClock, yep exactly, that was the reason why I checked the post to make sure that it was not a thank-you answer. The "it worked for me" did seem like a "thank you" answer if you looked at it from the queue (both mod and lqpq), but I looked at the post and then confirmed that it wasn't a thank-you answer and then declined the flags.

Answer (score 6):

When I encounter an answer similar to the form "It worked for me, *some explanation that looks like an answer.*" it's a decent indicator that it may be a "thank you" posted as an answer. If I can find the answer it's referring to, I'll:

- Add a comment indicating that this answer is actually a "thank you" comment directed to the other answer and provide a link. Adding this comment can be a useful indicator to the reviewers that the answer is just noise and not worth keeping. E.g.,

  > Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. This answer is a comment directed to *USER*'s [answer](*URL*). Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.
- Down-vote it.
- Flag it as "Not An Answer", or if I'm in the Low Quality Posts Review Queue, I'll recommend deletion because it's a "thank you" comment.